# Kendo Filtering wont work on Cascading ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, filtering, cascading

I'm trying to accomplished a `Client Filtering` on a `Cascading ComboBox` in `Kendo` but it seems that whenever I do a `Cascading ComboBox` the `Client Filtering` wont work but when I make a simple `ComboBox` the `Client Filtering` will work. Is there something wrong with my code?

Here's my code :

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                                .Name("office_id")
                                .DataTextField("office_name")
                                .Filter("contains")
                                .MinLength(2)
                                .Placeholder("Select Office . .")
                                .DataValueField("office_id")
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 80%;" })
                                .DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => { read.Action("ddlOffice", "Dropdowns"); });  })

)

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()

                                .Name("program_id")
                                .DataTextField("program_name")
                                .Placeholder("Select Program . .")
                                .DataValueField("program_id")
                                .Filter("contains")
                                .MinLength(2)
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 80%;" })

                                                .DataSource(source =>
                                                {
                                                    source.Read(read =>
                                                        {
                                                            read.Action("ddlProgram", "Dropdowns")
                                                                .Data("filterProgram");
                                                        })
                                                        .ServerFiltering(true);
                                })
                                .Enable(false)
                                .AutoBind(false)
                                .CascadeFrom("office_id")

         )
         <script>
            function filterProgram() {
                var OfficeDropdown = $("#office_id").val();
                return {
                    OfficeDropdown: OfficeDropdown
                }
            }
         </script>
```